# pandas sqlite read_sql dynamic in clause

Tags: pandas, sqlite, dataframe, parameters, read-sql

I am trying to use pandas read_sql function to query some data from sqlite DB. I need to use parameterized SQL which contains in clause (List) and some static parameters.

Below is my query

```
battingDataQuery = ('SELECT ID, MATCH_DATE, ROLE, DOWN_NUM, NAME, RUNS,' 
                    'MATCH_ID, TEAM_NAME, VERSUS_TEAM_NAME, GROUND_NAME ' 
               'FROM BATTING_DATA WHERE ID in ({1}) '
                'AND DOWN_NUM < {0} AND MATCH_TYPE = {0}')
```

I have added the placeholders appropriately using format

```
battingDataQuery = battingDataQuery.format('?', ','.join('?' * len(playerIdList)))
```

My generated SQL is as following

```
'SELECT ID FROM BATTING_DATA WHERE ID in (?,?,?,?,?) AND DOWN_NUM < ? AND MATCH_TYPE = ?'
```

I am stuck at the last part where I am sending the parameters as following:

```
battingDataDF = pd.read_sql_query(battingDataQuery , conn, params=(playerIdList,battingDownNum,'\'T20\''))
```

I am getting following error when using this

> Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 7,
> and there are 3 supplied.

I have tried using following variations but still get the same error

```
battingDataDF = pd.read_sql_query(battingDataQuery , conn, params=[playerIdList,battingDownNum,'\'T20\'']) # same error

battingDataDF = pd.read_sql_query(battingDataQuery , conn, params=[playerIdList,battingDownNum,'\'T20\'']) # same error

battingDataDF = pd.read_sql_query(battingDataQuery , conn, params=[tuple(playerIdList),battingDownNum,'\'T20\'']) # same error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should supply a list of 7 parameters for your 7 question marks:

```
battingDataDF = pd.read_sql_query(battingDataQuery , conn, params=playerIdList + [battingDownNum, "'T20'"])
```

(you supplied 3 parameters: a list of 5 numbers, a number and a string, hence the error)

Comment: @Neel: sorry for the multiple edits/deletions, now it's correct and tested.

Comment: thanks this worked. Although I was able to find another variation that worked

Answer (score 0):

Answer given my @stef worked but I was able to find another variation that worked. So wanted to post that for the sake of completion

```
battingDataDF = pd.read_sql_query(battingDataQuery , conn, params=(*playerIdList,battingDownNum,matchType))
```

*causes the list to be unpacked and thus resulting in supply of the correct number of arguments

Not sure which approach is better. If someone can post some light on this, it will be great.

Comment: I guess it's just a matter of taste: `playerIdList + [battingDownNum, "'T20'"]` converts the two last arguments to a list and than combines the two lists whereas `(*playerIdList, battingDownNum, "'T20'")` first unpacks the list and then converts all the arguments back into a tuple. So in both cases we get a list or tuple of all the arguments which [eventually are turned into a list and combined with the query statement](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/b5958ee1999e9aead1938c0bba2b674378807b3d/pandas/io/sql.py#L60-L65).

Comment: So I'd prefer the former solution as unpacking the list just to re-pack it into another list seems less intuitive to me, but as I said it's appears to be a matter of personal preference.